# How to do polynomial long division with absolute value?

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials

I wanted to know whether anyone can tell me how to solve i.e. $( 4x^5 + abs (x)^5 )$ : $( x^4 -4)$, because I want to find asymptotes.

Shall I look at :
$4x^5 + x^5$ and $4x^5 - x^5$ separately?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, treat both cases separately.

Comment: @MathJx : Thanks

Comment: @Aretino: Thanks you too

Comment: Note too that you can write $$\frac{4x^5+|x|^5}{x^4-4}=\frac{x^4(4x + |x|)}{x^4-4}$$ assuming you are dealing only with real numbers, if that helps

Comment: you have to do case work namely $$x\geq 0$$ or $$x<0$$

Answer (score 0):

i got $$1280 + 5120/(-4 + x) + 320 x + 80 x^2 + 20 x^3 + 5 x^4$$ for $$x\geq 0$$ and
$$3 x^4+12 x^3+48 x^2+192 x+\frac{3072}{x-4}+768$$ for $$x<0$$

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/557219)

Comment: i have described it i have cinsidered two cases $x\geq 0$ or $x<0$